# simulate network outage for database with testcontainers

Tags: java, testcontainers

I am trying to simulate a network outage with testcontainers.
I wanted to use a Socat container to expose the port, and then shot it down, and up again. I couldn't manage this as there are no halt.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy!

You need 2 containers, SocatContainer (provided by Testcontainers) and your target container. Connect them (Socat & target) with a network, see examples here:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/bcecd5cd9f9325517fd45db585312df2624315bb/core/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/containers/NetworkTest.java

When you need to simulate an outage, simply disconnect your target from the network (by using the Docker client you get with `DockerClientFactory.instance().client()` and `disconnectFromNetworkCmd`).

After you verify that the outage is handled correctly, connect your target to the network with `connectToNetworkCmd`).

An alternative solution would be to use Toxiproxy from Shopify:
https://github.com/shopify/toxiproxy. 
Start it in a container (with Testcontainers of course ;)) and use their Java client to apply the chaos operations.

Comment: cool! I will give a shot! I tried using Socat, but couldn't find the example.

Comment: SocatContainer's API is simple, but you could also gain some inspiration from, let's say, Kafka container.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is via testcontainers support for toxiproxy (https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/toxiproxy/).

Copy-pasting from the above web page:

```
E.g. // Create a common docker network so that containers can communicate
@Rule
public Network network = Network.newNetwork();

// the target container - this could be anything
@Rule
public GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer("redis:5.0.4")
    .withExposedPorts(6379)
    .withNetwork(network);

// Toxiproxy container, which will be used as a TCP proxy
@Rule
public ToxiproxyContainer toxiproxy = new ToxiproxyContainer()
    .withNetwork(network);
// To simulate an outage you do:

final ToxiproxyContainer.ContainerProxy proxy = toxiproxy.getProxy(redis, 6379);
proxy.setConnectionCut(true);
```